# Redirecting a list of pointers from one structure to another

Tags: c, pointers

I define a book structure containing a list of pointers to a chapter structure:

```
typedef struct chapter {
  int pages;
  //much more information
} chapter;

typedef struct book {
  chapter* all_chapter;
  int nb_chapter;
} book;
```

Now in my function I allocate 2 variables of type book. I am handling NULL pointers but to keep the code short i will leave it out!

```
book* first_book = malloc(sizeof(book));
first_book->nb_chapter = 5;
first_book->all_chapter = malloc(first_book->nb_chapter * sizeof(chapter));

book* snd_book = malloc(sizeof(book));
```

So now I want in some case the second variable snd_book to get all chapter pointers of the first book, but NOT to copy them but also to point to the same memory allocated, meaning if i then free `snd_book->chapter` then `first_book->chapter` is also empty.

But if I do

```
   snd_book->chapter = first_book->all_chapter;
```

then everything is being copied.

Do I need to maybe need to define the chapter as a two dimensional pointer or how can I achieve this?

Comment: No, `snd_book->all_chapter = first_book->all_chapter;` does not copy *"everything"*. How did you determine that that would be the case?

Comment: `snd_book->chapter` seems to be syntax error, too, what's the exact thing you're doing?

Comment: As UnholySheep has already mentioned, the pointer assignment does not copy everything. But it **does** copy the address allocated so if you call sth. like `free( first_book->all_chapter )`; first_book->all_chapter = NULL;` the pointer in `snd_book` will remain whatever it was before but accessing it will invoke UB. To avoid that you will indeed need pointers to pointers

Comment: Can you elaborate about what you are trying to achive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
book* first_book = malloc(sizeof(book));
first_book->nb_chapter = 5;
first_book->all_chapter = malloc(first_book->nb_chapter * sizeof(chapter));

book* snd_book = malloc(sizeof(book));
snd_book->all_chapter = first_book->all_chapter;
```

now you have two pointers to the same chapters

you have the pointer all_chapter from snd_book and from first_book point to the same blob you allocated. nothing is copied part from the address.

IOW

```
first_book->all_chapter = malloc(first_book->nb_chapter * sizeof(chapter))
```

Creates an array of chapters and `first_book->all_chapter` points to the first.

```
snd_book->all_chapter = first_book->all_chapter;
```

Makes `snd_book->all_chapter` point to the same as what `first_book->all_chapter` points to.

you should maybe also store the number of chapters in snd_book to know how many there are since a pointer does not convey that information.

```
snd_book->nb_chapter = first_book->nb_chapter;
```

Comment: Thank you for this step to step explanation, now i think this is a bit more clear. So snd_cook->all_chapter just keeps the memory which i have allocated using the first_book->all_chapter.

Answer (score 1):

**Current situation**

The book structure doesn't contain a list of pointers to chapters.  It contains a single pointer to a chapter or an array of chapters.

So indeed, when doing

```
    snd_book->all_chapter = first_book->all_chapter;
```

both books will share exactly the same content (eventually you could pretend that there are less chapters in the second book, but that's the only possible difference).

[image]

**Intended situation: independent sharable chapters**

If you want to share only some chapters, you need to work with a pointer to pointers to chapters instead of a pointer to chapters:

```
typedef struct book {
    chapter** all_chapter;
    int nb_chapter;
} book;
```

But this makes the initialization more complex:

```
// initialize an array of pointer to chapter  
first_book->all_chapter = calloc(first_book->nb_chapter, sizeof(chapter*));
// initialize each pointer in the array: 
for (int i=0; i< first_book->nb_chapter; i++) 
    first_book->all_chapter[i] = malloc (sizeof(chapter));
```

Of course, you'd need to handle null pointers as in your real code ;-)

Indeed, all this works a little bit like a 2D array, where the second dimension would always be 1.  But in reality it's a 1D array of pointers.

With this approach you could share selected chapters only.

[image]

This is however a risky structure: if the first book would clear a chapter, it would also be cleared in the second book.  However, if the first book would free a chapter, releasing its memory, the second book wouldn't be aware and might still use memory that should no longer be touched.  Worse:  if the second bokk would have some original (own chapters) and some shared, you wouldn't know for sure which ones should be freed and which ones would be freed by another book.

Comment: thank you for the explanation Cristophe! I am aware that the scenario like this one showed a risky structure as you mentioned, but in my code i am handling this differently, this was just for keeping the example short.

Comment: @malajedala I've illustrated the difference.  You could handle the risk for example by using a reference count in the chapter.  When a book discards a chapter, it would free the chapter if its reference count is 1 (no other books are using it) and just decrement the counter in the other cases.